# jQuery fading menu similar to Windows XP

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-selectors

I'd like to have a menu (select box replacement dropdown) that, when clicked, fades out but the selected option stays a little longer. As the title suggests, it's the same behaviour seen in Windows XP with all the "swanky" effects turned on - the menu fades away quickly, leaving the selected option to fade away slower.

My question is how to implement this using jQuery. I could use a selector to select all children of the parent element except the selected option, but it's messy; I'd ideally like a way of fading out the container and everything in it, but being able to fade out a single element inside it, which is excluded from the container animation.

Here is some sample HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Option</li>
    <li>Option</li>
    <li class="selected">Option</li>
    <li>Option</li>
    <li>Option</li>
</ul>
```

And some **pseudo** jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("ul").not("ul li.selected").fadeOut(200);
    $("li.selected").fadeOut(600);
});
```

I'm sorry if I haven't been clear enough - please leave a comment and I'll try to improve my wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not :)

### [DEMO (remake)](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/3sYm3/5/)

- Grab the position ( top/left ) of the selected element: `.position()`
- Get the html of the selected element
- Copy the html to a temp DIV and place that tiv on the same position where the clone was.
- Hide the options menu
- Hide later the temp DIV

  $('.options li').click(function(){
      var thisEl = $(this);
      var thisPos = thisEl.position();
      $('#temp').css({left:thisPos.left+'px', top:thisPos.top+'px'});
      $('#temp').html( thisEl.html() ).fadeTo(0, 1).delay(700).fadeTo(1000, 0, function(){
          $('#temp').empty();
      });
      $(".options").fadeToggle();
  });

Comment: A very neat demo there roXon! Thanks for putting the time and effort. I was looking for a simpler solution, but it appears there isn't one :-( This works well, although the option doesn't become re-selectable again when the menu is re-opened, but I can add that code in. Thanks for the starting push.

Comment: @Jam yes I am aware now afrer a pre-test thet are not selectable again but that's matter of a couple of lines less/more :) (BTW, I'll use it too on a future site ;) thanks for the idea! (if I may stole it!? ;) )

Comment: @James HERE! I reedited the demo. I needed just to clear the `#temp` once faded out! now tis works well! And I striped out a bit of code too.

Comment: Programming. Like a boss. Thank you so very much roXon. Of course you can steal my idea - I think it's quite a neat effect.

Comment: I agree! this is a rude one but with a bit of immagination... :)

Answer (score 1):

The part of your question that makes this a little tricky is "fading out the container and everything in it".

If you were to simply fade out the options with no concern for the container, then you could simply have one selector to fade out the non-selected options and another selector to fade out the selected options.

If you want to fade out the container all at once, then there's no getting around having to fade out the elements individually.  If you perform an operation on the container, then how can you exclude one sub-element from that operation short of moving it out of the container?

If you're looking to clean this up, you might try using the jQuery `.children` function to select all children of the container at once.  Then, you could loop thru them and fade everything out except for the one element that you want to fade out slower.

An alternative that comes to mind is that you could fade out the entire container, including the selected option on one line, and then immediately on the next line, use a selector to revert the selected option to show it it normally.  Finally, on the next line, you can fade the selected option out slowly.

Please let us know what you eventually figure out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer RFC. I'll look into your 3-line solution today and get back to you. It's a shame you can't get this behaviour more easily, although it's a rather isolated use case.

Comment: Follow up: I tried your idea above, and it didn't work unfortunately :-( @roXon has a good solution to my problem which _does_ work. Thanks again for your input :-)